# How to Retrieve Assembly information from within DLL

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dll

I have an ASP.Net asmx web site service, which has an AssemblyInfo.cs inside the Properties folder. I am having trouble accessing the information inside that file.

My assumption was that I should be able to call

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
```

and then get information from that file, however I get some other Assembly.
To solve that issue I moved my assembly attributes from that file into my Global.asax.cs page. After doing that calling the above line returned me the expected values.

**1. Do I have to do it this way or have I just over looked something regarding the AssemblyInfo.cs file?**

This website also has a DLL which is trying to use information from that same AssemblyInfo.cs. I cannot figure out how to get the information I need from within the DLL.

```
Assembly.GetEntryAssembly() = null
Assembly.GetCallingAssembly() = mscorlib
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly() = DLL Assembly
```

**2. How can I get the assembly information of the Site?**

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using GatewayProtocol;
using Steno;
[assembly: Guid("3d5900ae-aaaa-bbbb-cccc-d9e4606ca793")]
//If I remove the above line, the below Debug line **does not** return the expected Guid

namespace GWS
{

public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Logger.Init();

        var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        var attribute = (GuidAttribute)assembly.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(GuidAttribute), true)[0];
        Debug.WriteLine(attribute.Value) //3d5900ae-aaaa-bbbb-cccc-d9e4606ca793
    }
}
```

}

Inside Logger.Init() it starts a thread with a loop reading a queue

```
var guid = ((GuidAttribute)Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(GuidAttribute), true)[0]).Value;
```

This returns the GUID of the DLL, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

AssemblyInfo.cs in web application

```
[assembly: Guid("df21ba1d-f3a6-420c-8882-92f51cc31ae1")]
```

Global.asax.cs

```
public class Global : HttpApplication
{
    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Logger.Init();
        string assemblyName = Logger.AssemblyGuid; // to test under debug
    }
}
```

WebService1.asmx.cs

```
namespace WebApplicationSO2
{
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    public class WebService1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        public string HelloWorld() {
            Assembly a = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            var attribute = (GuidAttribute)a.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(GuidAttribute), true)[0];
            var guidFromDll = Logger.AssemblyGuid;
            return "My Guid: " + attribute.Value + " Guid from Dll: " + guidFromDll; // returns 'My Guid: df21ba1d-f3a6-420c-8882-92f51cc31ae1 Guid from Dll: df21ba1d-f3a6-420c-8882-92f51cc31ae1'

        }
     }
}
```

Dll:

```
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Logger
    {
        public static string AssemblyGuid;

        public static void Init() {
            Assembly a = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly();
            var attribute = (GuidAttribute)a.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(GuidAttribute), true)[0];
            AssemblyGuid = attribute.Value;
        }
    }
}
```